# Python ,How to use selenium send keys the password field of this site?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem when I use webdriver `send_keys` to the password field of this site : https://fx.yiji.com

I can focus on the password field but the `send_keys` command not working on this field .!

Code:

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

iedriver = 'C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEDriverServer.exe'
os.environ['webdriver.ie.driver'] = iedriver

browser = webdriver.Ie(iedriver)
browser.get('https://fx.yiji.com')

click_login = browser.find_element_by_id('forLogin')
click_login.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

user = browser.find_element_by_name('username')
user.send_keys('my_email')

password = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.text.ignore.js-pass-guard')
password.send_keys('my_password')
```

Comment: Thank you for improved my question format  @Narendra Rajput

Comment: No one can solve this problem?